# Is there a way to perform batch interpolation in ArcGIS from 1 excel file?

Tags: r, interpolation, arcgis, arcpy

I have an excel file with station weather data. For each station, for each year (70 years), I have temperature data, as well as associated latitude and longitude of the stations. I want to create interpolated raster maps (using IDW) for each year for temperature.

My excel files are set up like this, but with 70 years of data:
[image]

I would therefore like 70 interpolated maps for each year of temperature. It also may be important to note that the stations for each year are not all the same.

I am willing to try to do this as a batch process in ArcGIS, but find that can be tedious. Is there a faster way to do this, through arcpy or even through R?

Comment: coordinates?! Have a look at [here](https://rpubs.com/hungle510/202761) you just need to filter data for each year.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the coordinates above after editing the post. That link is helpful here, any thoughts on how to easily automate this for each year?

Comment: Simply you can use an if-then approach or apply a function list of data using `lapply` for example.